# How to change size of panel control on resize of parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using this code to change size of a `panel` control for `maximize` and `normal state`, and it's working fine, but I am not getting how to re-size panel according to my background image when the user will re-size the form other than minimize,maximize and normal state, i.e using the mouse. how do I do this using some calculation code or any other way?

```
private void ParentHome_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        this.Panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(227, 324);
        this.Panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(69, 223);
    }
    else if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        this.Panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(198, 289);
        this.Panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 193);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle any event. Just use the `Anchor` property:

```
Panel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | 
                AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

Comment: I tried anchor property but that doesn't fits to my back ground image, hence used this event, this code I am using for background image streching `foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl is MdiClient)
                {
                    ctl.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.bg;
                    this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
                    break;
                }                
            }` on resize of form how do i change panel size

Comment: @Durga could you post some screen shot to show how it doesn't fit to your BackgroundImage when using Anchor? Because if it doesn't work for you with Anchor, **it also can't work for you by resizing the panel yourself**. In fact **Anchor** is called resizing and positioning automatically**.

Comment: Stretch uses a multiplier, Anchor doesn't.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't even understand what exactly the user wants to stretch, according to the  question title, resizing should be done with correct Anchor settings. BTW, what do you mean by `multiplier`?

Comment: I have added image showing normal staet (left ) and resized state(right),dat panel is going outside dat orange box in background image

Comment: @Durga looks like the `Anchor` is not affected correctly. I can see that the size of your panel is the same as in normal state and resized state. What's the Parent of your panel?

Comment: @Durga BTW, your problem should be rephrased. What's the `orange box`? Is it just a box painted on the BackgroundImage? If you want to keep something inside that `orange box` when resizing the `BackgroundImage`, of course `Anchor` won't work BUT resizing it yourself is not easy. You have to know the **size and position scales** of the `orange box` relative to the `BackgroundImage`. Anyway you seem to have a wrong approach to solve your actual problem.

Comment: same form is parent form of panel, orange box is part of image painted at background